# Fetching values from tables and adding other parameters in Insert Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

Can anyone please advice in below query - I need to fetch few from table and few will be provided as a variables to below statement. I'm struggling how to write this

```
SQLCommand = New SqlCommand("TableA", Conn)
SQLCommand.CommandText = "Insert into TableA(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8) " & _
            "Values (@p1, @P2, @P3, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7, @P8)
```

Out of this @p1,@p2,@p3,@p4 will come from Table B
And @p5,@p6, @p7, @p8 will be variables to whom value will be provided by the function

I'm struggling how to change the above COMMANDTEXT statement - to fetch values from TableB and also other custom variables (which are p5,p6,p7,p8)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into TableA (P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8) 
     SELECT b.column1, b.column2, b.column3, b.column4, @P5, @P6, @P7, @P8
     FROM TableB b
     WHERE ...
```

Comment: Then how would I declare these parameters and their value. Means _Command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.Int))             _SQLCommand.Parameters(0).Value = column1. Is this correct then?

Comment: Almost. The names have to match: there is no `@p1` in my sample, I started with `@p5`.

Comment: With this approach - if I define parameters then it gives me error. SQLCommand.Parameters(0).Value = column1 (says column1 is not defined)